# blocked links in sitemap

Tags: robots.txt, sitemap

i'm using a [online sitemap generator tool](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) which generates links even for which are blocked in **robots.txt**. Is these blocked links affect *site ranking* ? . Is there anyway to overcome it ?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have made a robots.txt file that blocks the pages, it shouldn't affect your ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried emailing the developer of the sitemaps tool you use? Maybe they can help you, so the tool obeys your robots.txt file